# How to show that $x^2 - 37y^2 =2$ does not have integer solutions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, pell-type-equations

We need to prove that $x^2 - 37y^2 =2$ does not have integer solutions.

I have two angles I thought about approaching it from:

1. Since 37 is prime, I can show that for $x$ not divisible by $37$, we have $x^{36} ≡ 1mod(37)$ but I don't see how that's useful

---

2. I could manipulate the equation and make it to: $x^2 - 4 = 37y^2 - 2$
   $\implies (x-2)(x+2) = 37y^2 - 2$

Then if the RHS is even, then $y^2$ is even $\implies$ $y^2$ ends with $0, 4,$ or $6$ $\implies$ $37y^2$ ends with $0, 8,$ or $2$

$\implies 37y^2 -2$ ends with $0, 6,$ or $8$

But then I reach a dead end here too

---

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: $2$ is not a quadratic residue $\pmod{37}$, end of story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2-37y^2=2\Rightarrow x^2-y^2\equiv2\mod(4)\Rightarrow x^2\equiv 2+y^2\mod(4)$$
but $2+y^2\equiv 2\mod(4)$ or $2+y^2\equiv 3\mod(4)$ since any square has remainder $0$ or $1$ when divided by $4$. Either case is impossible since $x^2$ is a square itself.

Comment: I don't understand how $x^2 - 37y^2 = 2 \implies x^2-y^2 ≡ 2 mod(4)$

Comment: when you divide both sides by $4$ the remainders should be the same for both sides. Note $37=36+1\equiv 1\mod(4)$.

Answer (score 7):

There are no integer solutions to
$$ x^2 - 37 y^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 4   $$ as

$$ x^2 - 37 y^2 \equiv x^2 -  y^2 \pmod 4   $$

Comment: I don't understand why this is the case

Comment: @iphonex The squares modulo $4$ are $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @egreg oh i see! thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If there were a solution, then you could take the equation mod $37$ and find $$x^2\equiv 2\pmod{37}$$

In particular, $2$ would be a [quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) modulo $37$.  However, it isn't, since the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) $\left(\frac{2}{37}\right)=-1$.

Comment: I never thought of it like that. Thank you! Do you think any of my other two ways would somehow work?

Comment: In particular, for any odd prime $p$, 2 is a quadratic residue $\pmod p$ if and only if $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{8}$ - or as another way of saying the same thing you'll sometimes see, $(\frac{2}{p}) = (-1)^{(p^2-1)/8}$.

Comment: @iphonex You could stretch a point to link to your "angle" #1 and say that since $2^{18}\not\equiv 1\bmod 37$, there is no $x^2\equiv 2$ since that would imply that $(x^2)^{18}\equiv x^{36}\equiv 1 \bmod 37$ by Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2 - 37y^2 = 2$ is even.  So as $odd \pm even = odd$, $even + even = even$, $odd + odd = even$ we can see that either $x^2$ and $37y^2$ are either both even or both odd and we can pursue that and get a contradiction.

But now would be a nice time to point out that for all integer $m^2 \not \equiv 2 \mod 4$ and $m^2 \not \equiv 3 \mod 4$ and that either $m^2 \equiv 0 \mod 4$ or $m^2 \equiv 1 \mod 4$.

Prook:  Let $m = 2k + i$ where $i= 0,1$.  Then $m^2 \equiv 4k^2 + 4ki +i^2 \equiv i^2 \mod 4$.  And $i^2$ is either $0$ or $1$.

So $x^2 \equiv \{0,1\} \mod 4$ and $37y^2 \equiv y^2 \equiv \{0,1\} \mod 4$.

So $x^2 - 37y^2 \equiv \{0,1\} - \{0,1\} \equiv \{0-0,0-1,1-0,1-1\} \equiv \{0,3,1,0\} \mod 4$.  And $x^2 - 37y^2 \equiv 2 \mod 4$ is just about the only possibility  that can never happen.